# Branch commits don't go instantly to PR

Tags: bitbucket

We use Bitbucked for source control (git).

Following situation:

1. I created branch
2. added 3 commits to it
3. created PR

I see 3 commits in this PR.

Then I added additional commit to branch.

I see 4 commits in this branch, but still 3 in PR.

Sometimes it takes several hours for commits (which added after submitting PR) to appear in PR. But sometimes it's almost instantly.

I worked with Bitbucket before and changes in branch always appear in PR instantly.

Why it takes some time to update PR? It is normal? Or configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found [this article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/pull-requests-not-reflecting-changes-pushed-to-remote-branch-779171762.html) on Bitbusket site:

> Bitbucket Server relies on hook scripts that are installed into each
>   repository (and managed by the system) to provide change information
>   that, in turn, allows it to update pull requests and check branch
>   permissions. If the hooks are not installed correctly, or are damaged,
>   these required callbacks do not happen and the functionality
>   associated with them fails.